# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute during select

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> Unhandled exception has occurred. System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource)
>       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable`1 source)
>       at Check.get_TotalChange()
>       at CheckChanged(ICheck check)

If I run my code like 5 thousand times per day like 2 times it will result in this error and the program will crash.. What's wrong with my code? I followed the exception information and I think this is the code that may cause the exception. Anyone have an idea what kind of problem that is?

```
public decimal TotalChange
{
    get
    {
        var change = (from IPayment payment in _payments where payment.Amount < 0 select payment.Amount).Sum();
        var paid = (from IPayment payment in _payments select payment.Amount).Sum();
        return paid <= Total && Total > 0 ? Math.Abs(change) : paid - Total;
    }
}
```

I changed it up to:

```
    private readonly object _totalChangeLock = new object();
    public decimal TotalChange
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_totalChangeLock)
            {
                var change =
                    (from IPayment payment in _payments where payment.Amount < 0 select payment.Amount).Sum();
                var paid = (from IPayment payment in _payments select payment.Amount).Sum();
                return paid <= Total ? Math.Abs(change) : paid - Total;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I do have 2 methods that modify _payments. I locked them too. Hope that doesn't cause any issues.

```
    public void AddPayment(IPayment payment)
    {
        lock (_paymentsLock)
        {
            if (_payments.Contains(payment)) return;
            _payments.Add(payment);
        }
    }

    public void RemovePayment(IPayment payment)
    {
        lock (_paymentsLock)
        {
            if (_payments.Contains(payment))
                _payments.Remove(payment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assumption: you are doing things in a multithreaded way. The collections change while you're enumerating them, as the error says, since you're not using any locking mechanisms.

Comment: @Wkjjjj  is this method called in a loop

Comment: You are right, I'm using multithreads and multiple threads can call to this method from different places at the same time. So I just need to lock _payments I guess?

Comment: @Wkjjjj Exactly. just like dlxeon did in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you modify _payments  variable from another thread while your TotalChange property code is being executed.

If this is true, try avoid multithread access to _payments variable or consider use locking while doing read/write access to _payments variable

```
lock(_lockerObject)
{
    // Do operations that modify _payments collection
    _payments.Add();//...
}

    public decimal TotalChange
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockerObject)
            {
                var change = (from IPayment payment in _payments where payment.Amount < 0 select payment.Amount).Sum();
                var paid = (from IPayment payment in _payments select payment.Amount).Sum();
            }
            return paid <= Total && Total > 0 ? Math.Abs(change) : paid - Total;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I just need to lock _payments while I'm executing this?

Comment: Thank you, @ckruczek. Added code sample. You need to lock both when you update your collection and when you iterate it. Issue happens when collection is changed during iteration.

Comment: Ahh yes this looks much better now.

Comment: for the most of the time you are computing TotalChange you cannot add items to `_payments`

Comment: It really depends how frequently you add new records and how long calculations are executing. Solution to do copy of whole list is producing unwanted garbage in memory, spending time on doing list copy and then garbage collecting it. In real environment lock may be more efficient solution.

Comment: You need lock anyway. if the list is 10 items long but the computation takes a lot if time your assumption is incorrect. I get what you mean, but you cannot summarize this in one rule of thumb.

Comment: Yes, I understand lock is required anyway. Difference between my and your solution is that you lock only list cloning, while I lock whole calculation to prevent list cloning. In some cases one solution or another may be better.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this, most simple one is to work on another list, so you can add `_payments`:

```
public decimal TotalChange
{
    get
    {
        lock(_syncObj)
        {
           var p = _payments.ToList();
        }            

        var change = (from IPayment payment in p where payment.Amount < 0 select payment.Amount).Sum();
        var paid = (from IPayment payment in p select payment.Amount).Sum();
        return paid <= Total && Total > 0 ? Math.Abs(change) : paid - Total;
    }
}
```

And you also need to lock it when you add items:

```
lock(_syncObj)
{
    _payments.Add();//...
}
```